# How to place the Magento forms fields side by side

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, forms, custom-field

I want to place my form fields side by side as in the image below. i am aware that you can style the individual forms elements within the fieldset. however in my situation i want to place two form filed side by side.

am i correct in assuming that i have to make a custom page to do this and then render the fields manually. Or is it possible to use CSS from within the form filed to render them side by side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to add new tab in Edit/Tabs.php then in edit/tab/yourtabname.php just set your own template using method setTemplate() and do what you want in your templatename.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by adding a bootstrap columns, besides it's pretty and it manage also the responsive.

Assuming that you want to put a contact form fields side by side.

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/contacts/form.phtml`

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" id="name" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="required-entry form-control form-control-1 input-form-left" placeholder="Nom*:">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="required-entry validate-email form-control form-control-1" type="text" placeholder="Email*:"/>
    </div>
    // other fields...
    <div class="buttons-set input-form">
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

If you want to make a `name` and `email` fields side by side, you have to add this cols `<div class="col-md-6">` for each

It becomes like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
<div class="row"> //add
    <div class="col-md-6"> //add
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" id="name" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="required-entry form-control form-control-1 input-form-left" placeholder="Nom*:">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> //add
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="required-entry validate-email form-control form-control-1" type="text" placeholder="Email*:"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    // other fields...
    <div class="buttons-set input-form">
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

For more informations: [Bootstrap Grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

Comment: hi prince. thanks for advice. question: does that then mean that i will be manually calling my form. i mean, the magento form system is quite good. i am worried about breaking away from this and manually creating the form

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean but you can modify the form of other form the moment you don't make errors